# How to create a sequential unique id for a db field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the table Slug with the field url which is unique.

If I create `@slug = Slug.url = "foo"`

When I go to save, if Slug.url of "foo" already exists, I would like to then try for a Slug.url of "foo-1" if that also exists, try "foo-2" foo-3, foo-4, etc. until a value is found that doesn't exist and can be created in the database. What would be the right way to go about this in my Rails model?

### Update

My latest code looks like this:

```
  def set_url
    self.url = self.title.parameterize
    # Ensure the url is available
    qUrl = self.url.split('-').shift
    slugs = Slug.where("url like '#{qUrl}%'")
    if slugs.exists?
      c = slugs.count + 1
      self.url = self.url + "-" + c.to_s
    end
  end
```

The problem with this code is the qUrl is picking up false positives, any time a title starts with the word "why" slugs are being found. Is there an approach that is more reliable and elegant?

Comment: You may try `before_save` callback. And check there if url is **foo-1**, then take `slug.url.last.to_i + 1` as new slug

Comment: @Abhi not sure I follow, would you mind posting a full answer?

Comment: Unless your server is single-threaded, you'd better think hard about locking to prevent races among multiple requests with the same URL.

Comment: Could you please show how you plan to use `Slug`, where and with which attributes?

Comment: Are you using FriendlyID or not? If not, are you partial to using it?

Comment: I am not using FriendlyID, that did not meet the requirements as it would add an identifier in the URL like "/articles" which I need to avoid.

Comment: what is the database you use?

Comment: Postgres on heroku

Comment: @AnApprentice since [v5.2.0](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/blob/master/Changelog.md#520-2016-12-01) ([PR #735](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/pull/735)), `friendly_id` supports a `:routes` config option that allows you to disable all modifications to the Rails routes, so the library really does nothing else to your model besides generate a unique slug before saving. See my answer below for a complete example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's complete setup instructions for a Rails project with multiple Models all using the same Slug model, with slug-URL routes configured at the root:

#### 1. Slug Model

Use [`friendly_id`](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id)'s [`sequentially_slugged`](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/blob/master/lib/friendly_id/sequentially_slugged.rb) module, which generates sequentially-ordered slugs from a unique column when a record is saved (specifically, during the `before_validation` callback.

Start a new Rails project in a new directory:

```
rails new .
```

Add `friendly_id` to `Gemfile` (and run `bundle install` after):

```
gem 'friendly_id'
```

Generate your `slugs` table schema with a migration (run `rake db:migrate` after), `db/migrate/20170114211811_create_slugs.rb`:

```
class CreateSlugs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :slugs do |t|
      t.string :url
      t.string :title
    end
    add_index :slugs, :url, unique: true
    add_reference :slugs, :item, polymorphic: true, index: true
  end
end
```

Create a `Slug` model using `friendly_id`, `app/models/slug.rb`:

```
class Slug < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title,
    use: :sequentially_slugged,
    slug_column: :url
  belongs_to :item, polymorphic: true
end
```

#### 2. Slug Route + Controller

Your use case asks for a single root route (e.g., `/this-is-my-x`).

`config/routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get ':url' => 'slugs#show'
end
```

To serve multiple Models from this single Slug route, you can have your Slug Controller delegate its `render` action to the View corresponding to the selected Slug's associated Model.

`app/controllers/slugs_controller.rb`:

```
class SlugsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @item = Slug.find_by(url: params[:url])
    render "#{@item.item_type.pluralize.underscore}/show"
  end
end
```

#### 3. Sluggable Models + Views

Finally, start using the single Slug from multiple Models.

Generate an `Article` schema + model:

```
rails generate model article title:string
```

`app/models/article.rb`:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :slug, as: :item
  before_validation do
    if slug.try(:title) != title
      self.slug = Slug.create(title: title)
    end
  end
end
```

`app/views/articles/show.html.erb`:

```
<h1>Articles#show</h1>
<p>Title is <%=@item.title%>, ID is <%=@item.id%></p>
```

Then create more Models+Views for blogs, tags, etc.

#### 4. Test

Create a few Articles in `rails console`:

```
(1..10).each { Article.create title: 'foo' }
```

Test your slug (run `rails server`, and visit `localhost:3000/foo-7`):

```
Articles#show
Title is foo, ID is 7
```

All done!

Comment: I love this idea but can you show how this would work with multiple models (articles, blogs, tags), and not have anything prepended in the URL... so it's just /this-is-my-x  ... I don't see where in the Slugs model above the records know which model to use and where to route. Would love to see what the router is supposed to look like.

Comment: @AnApprentice thanks for the extra context, I think I understand what you're looking for now. I've edited my post to include full route/controller/model setup instructions for using a single Slug table with multiple independent Models.

Comment: Very nice. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest using the [friendly_id gem](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) for this. If you look at the [documentation in the slugged object](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/blob/master/lib/friendly_id/slugged.rb), you'll see that it has a mechanism to handle uniqueness by appending a uuid to the slug name.

Alternatively, there are a number of [other slug generating gems](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_permalinks___slugs) that might work better for your environment.

Comment: Thanks but sadly that gem doesn't meet my SEO requirements. Like quora, I don't want a appended modle name in the urls site.com/articles or site.com/blogs/ etc...

Comment: FWIW friendly_id allow you to specify a model method that will generate the slug.

Comment: @engineerDave how can I use friendly_id in a way where there is nothing prepended to the actual ID.. Meaning no "/articles" etc, I need multiple models to work across root

Comment: @engineerDave for what resource you need slug, if that resource has any title like attribute, then making it uniq case insensitive, and using that with friendly_id gem would make more sense, title like attribute should be human entered to have it SEO stuff

Comment: @AnApprentice that would be controlled by your routing and might get a little tricky because its somewhat deviating from Rails' conventions

Comment: @AmolPujari you could use something like a title column to make a slug but honestly SEO is to a degree black magic, google should be fine with the features of friendly_id's slugs IMO

Answer (score 1):

What I was suggesting is to use a `before_save` callback (I haven't tried the code, but answering conceptually):

**Slug Model**

```
before_save :check_and_generate_unique_slug

private

def check_and_generate_unique_slug
  is_unique = Slug.where(url: self.url).count > 0 ? false : true

  unless is_unique
    #if say previous url was foo-1, self.url.last.to_i gives 1
    new_url = "foo-#{self.url.last.to_i + 1}" #here it's foo-2
    self.url = new_url
    self.check_and_generate_unique_slug
  else
    self.url = new_url
  end
end
```

**NOTE** Even if initially url is "foo", `"foo".last.to_i` will give 0, and next url would be **foo-#{0 + 1} = foo-1**

**EDIT**

**A Better way**

```
def check_and_generate_unique_slug
  urls = Slug.pluck(:url).uniq
  #=> ["foo", "foo-1", "foo-3", "foo-2"]

  latest_url_code = urls.map{|a| a.last.to_i}.uniq.sort.last
  #=> urls.map{|a| a.last.to_i}.uniq.sort  gives  [0, 1, 2, 3]
  #=> last will give 3

  self.url = "foo-#{latest_url_code + 1}"
end
```

**EDIT**

As mentioned in comment `last could be a 2 digit`

Code can be modified as: `"foo-xxx".split("-").last.to_i`

Comment: last could be a 2 digit

Comment: @amol Right, then the code can be "foo-xxx".split("-").last.to_i

Comment: It may need a unique index in the slug database & handling code for that particular SQL exception in `check_and_generate_unique_slug`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
before_save :generate_slug

private

def genareate_slug
  url = self.name.to_s.parameterize(title)
  count = Slug.where("url LIKE '#{url}'").count
  self.url = count.positive? ? "#{url}-#{count + 1}" : url
end
```

Comment: That will create falses matches Example "Hello World" will later be picked up by "Hello"

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class Slug < ActiveRecord::Base     

  before_validation :set_slug, :on => :create

  protected 

  def set_slug
    tmp = "#{ title.downcase.gsub(/[^a-z0-9]+/i, '-') }"
    i = 0
    self.url = loop do
      tmp.concat("-#{ i }") if i > 0
      i += 1
      break tmp unless Slug.exists?(url: tmp)
    end
  end

end
```

try it in console.

```
tmp1 = Slug.create!(title: 'hello world')
tmp1.url #=> "hello-world"

tmp2 = Slug.create!(title: 'Hello World')
tmp2.url #=> "hello-world-1"
```

Comment: but when the title is just "Hello" it will create a false match.